# Trying to insert random image generated from another table in a table

Tags: c#, sql-server

The page displays some random image and the name associated with it on the form from a table where all the images are stored. I want to store the random image generated in some other table so that I can use it later. But as I try to insert the random image generated in some other table, it throws an error:

> System.Drawing.Bitmap

Also , I have already included `MultipleActiveResultSets=True` so that query works even though another query is being iterated already.
The exception stack :-

---

```
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)

   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)

   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)

   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean& dataReady)

   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteNonQueryTds(String methodName, Boolean async, Int32 timeout, Boolean asyncWrite)

   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.InternalExecuteNonQuery(TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, String methodName, Boolean sendToPipe, Int32 timeout, Boolean asyncWrite)

   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

---

The code is as follows:-

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                String sql = "select top 1 name,pic from fruits order by NEWID()";

            if (conn.State != ConnectionState.Open)
                conn.Open();
            cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, conn);
            SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            reader.Read();
            if (reader.HasRows)
            {
                textFruit.Text = reader[0].ToString();
                byte[] img = (byte[])(reader[1]);
                if (img == null)
                {
                    picFruit.Image = null;
                }
                else
                {
                    MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(img);
                    picFruit.Image = Image.FromStream(ms);
                    string sql_2 = "insert into solution values("+textFruit.Text + ","+picFruit.Image +")";
                    cmd = new SqlCommand(sql_2, conn);
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    MessageBox.Show("Inserted into Solutions");
                }
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("No record exists");
            }
            conn.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception exc)
        {
            conn.Close();
            MessageBox.Show(exc.Message);
        }
    }
```

Comment: post the full exception stack

Comment: Is the text name a primary key?   When you have a primary key you can only insert one row with same key.  If the key exists then you have to use Update. cmd.ExecuteNonQuery(); returns an integer indicating number of rows changed.  When using Update you will get zero if item is not in table then you have to use Insert.  When you use insert and get zero the item is already in the table and then you have to use Update.

Comment: There is no primary key in that table.

Comment: Please don't use string concatenation to write SQL Queries. Read up on parameters. Here you're suffering from multiple issues in the SQL you're generating (try *inspecting* `sql_2` in the debugger before it runs to see them)

Comment: Okay, thank you. I will look into parameters to execute queries. I started working with c# today and referred to some videos online to code the requirement.